# How to follow network adapter state?

Tags: scom

How to follow network adapter's state in system center operations manager. I want to have alert in system center operations manager when network adapter is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

In standard Windows OS (if you use Windows) Management Packs there are two NIC related monitors: "Network Adapter Connection Health", which is disable by default, and "Network Interface State Monitor", which is enabled. However, none of them alert if a connection is disabled. It's done for a strong reason, because usually disable status means "I don't need it, please don't monitor it.".

If you explicitly need to monitor Disabled status, you need to use a 3rd party Management Pack (if exists) or create your own.

Best regards
Max

Comment: Thank you, Max.

Best regards, Dragan